# Middle extrusion for mesh in Three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, blender

I'm currently creating a three js app and I just want to ask if this is possible. So my goal is create a model in blender that's like mesh #1 on the image below, export it thru blender gltf exporter by KhronosGroup, import it in Three JS and extrude the mesh in the middle to achieve mesh #2 in the image below.

The reason for doing this is I need to display a model that could have a dynamic length and let user control the length of the model thru the app's UI.

Is this possible? If not, is there a way for me to achieve the behavior that I need to accomplish?

[image]

Comment: What about using [`THREE.ExtrudeGeometry()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry)/[`THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeBufferGeometry)?

Comment: Seems like the mesh in the imported object is a BufferGeometry. How do I use this mesh data to utilize the funtionalities in ExtrudeGeometry/ExtrudeBufferGeometry?

Comment: I mean to use those geometries straight in the scene, instead of the model from Blender. Could you post this question on the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/)? With a live code example (jsfiddle, codepen etc.), using your model.

Comment: I can't create a fiddle for this because I would need to host the gltf files to be able to load them to the app and I don't have anywhere to host it. I also want to utilize blender since the model wouldn't be as simple as the sample mesh on the image above which means it would be too difficult to programatically create the mesh

Comment: I use github for that purpose. it's easy to use files from there on jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks

Comment: This sounds a bit like [9-slice scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9-slice_scaling) in 3D. You could scale the model down to a (-1,1) range in each dimension, and then use a custom vertex shader that would manipulate the vertices based on their location. Something along the lines of `if (vPos.x > 0.5) { vPos.x += 0.5 * uWidthModifier; } else if (vPos.x < -0.5) { vPos.x -= 0.5 * uWidthModified; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Scale the model down to a unit bbox, and use a custom vertex shader that manipulates the vertices based on their model space location.

```js
const vs = `
uniform float uWidthModifier;
void main() 
{
  vec3 p = position;
  if (p.x > 0.33) {
    p.x += 0.5 * uWidthModifier;
  } else if (p.x < -0.33) {
    p.x -= 0.5 * uWidthModifier;
  }
 vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(p, 1.0);
 gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;
}
`;

const fs = `
void main() {
 gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
`;

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1);
let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    uWidthModifier: { value: 0 }
  },
  fragmentShader: fs,
  vertexShader: vs,
  wireframe: true
});
let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
scene.add(cube);
camera.position.z = 5;

document.getElementById('inc').addEventListener('click', function() {
  material.uniforms.uWidthModifier.value += 0.5;
});
document.getElementById('dec').addEventListener('click', function() {
  material.uniforms.uWidthModifier.value -= 0.5;
});

function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

```css
#config {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.js"></script>
<div id="config">
  uWidthModifier:
  <button id="inc">+</button>
  <button id="dec">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be great to provide a live code example with this solution.

Comment: Good example :) The same approach could be applied at the side of javascript, modifying vertices themselves.

Comment: Thanks @prisoner849, I wasn't sure if there was a way to link an existing jsfiddle snippet here, but I tried copy/pasting my code into the live code snippet here :)